# Why is this 777 with doors and windows covered?

Tags: aircraft-storing

[image: singapore777]

It's in the desert somewhere and it has its windows and landing gear and doors covered. Why is it that? Of course, it's not in service anymore...
[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled-(Singapore-Airlines)/Boeing-777-212-ER/2784912/&sid=95a59c577a5258e799c5da51bae50628)

Comment: On a random note: This airplane actually looks like a balloon under the lighting conditions and the coverings.

Comment: The legend of this image on the [original site](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled-(Singapore-Airlines)/Boeing-777-212-ER/2784912/) is quite informative: "*EI-FGT (cn 28530/390) Ex Singapore Airlines 9V-SQI, in deep storage configuration for almost a year now (arrived in VCV 2/23/15), and so far seems to have an uncertain future.* [VCV storage](http://articles.latimes.com/2009/mar/15/business/fi-boneyard15).

Comment: That's in Marana, Az in the United States and it's been decommissioned.

Comment: @Citizen: Welcome! You are right about an aircraft boneyard location, however the [photographer](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled-%28Singapore-Airlines%29/Boeing-777-212-ER/2784912/) indicates the photo was shot in Victorville Southern California Logistics airport (former George AFB - VCV). [More on VCV](http://www.airplaneboneyards.com/southern-california-logistics-airport-victorville-boneyard.htm).

Comment: Oh nice.  I missed that.  Thanks.  I'm in Az and go by the Marana boneyard occasionally. As well the former afb in Tucson.  Looked just like Marana to me. Ty for clarifying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The aircraft is in storage. The Boeing 777-212(ER) seems to operated by Singapore Airlines under [lease from Pembroke](http://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapid=1055101) before being [withdrawn from use in Dec 2014](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/777/28530/EI-FGT-Pembroke). After that, the aircraft is under storage at [Southern California Logistics Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_California_Logistics_Airport).

The windows are covered in aluminium foil for storage; however, the engines appear to be still there (which will usually be removed), which indicates that the storage was planned for only a short time.

Answer (score 13):

Currently that airplane is in storage per [planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/777/28530/EI-FGT-Pembroke). The reason why it is stored in the desert is because the environment would not cause some structural damage to the airframe. All those doors and windows are covered to keep animals, dust, and even sunlight out so that they would not damage the airframe either.

You can read more about storing aircraft in the desert [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_boneyard) and [here](http://www.johnweeks.com/boneyard/).

Answer (score 4):

The aircraft was previously operated by Singapore Airlines but has been returned to Pembroke Leasing. It is probably in storage because it is not economical to sell or lease at the present time.

Here are some possible reasons why it may be uneconomical to sell or lease:

1) excessive supply of aircraft for market conditions

2) cabin or seating configuration

3) excessive hours on the aircraft, engines or components

4) age of the aircraft (14 years)